# how to split a return text become individual string in extjs?

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I want to split a returning text to become an individual string but i am noobie in extjs.Pls help me if any idea with it...thankz

my example code:

```
//my return "record" string is "1: 3-4-2011 to 9-4-2011"
Ext.getCmp('cboWeek').on('select', function(box, record, index) 
{    
    DateFrom = new Date(record).format('m/d/Y');//split to 3-4-2011
    DateTo = new Date(record).format('m/d/Y');  //split to 9-4-2011      
    Store.load({ params: {dateFrom : DateFrom, dateTo: DateTo }});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think what you want is:

```
// if record is "1: 3-4-2011 to 9-4-2011"
var matches = record.match(/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/g);
// matches[0] will be 3-4-2011 and matches[1] will be 9-4-2011
Store.load({ params: {dateFrom : matches[0], dateTo: matches[1] }});
</pre>
```

just a note: your dates are not what can be parsed using Date object neither using Ext.Date.parse, because month / day must be 2digits, if you manage to get 3-4-2011 to something like 03-04-2011 by doing `"3-4-2011".replace(/([0-9]{1})[^0-9]+/g, '0$1-')` you can get Date object using parse method of ext's date: `Ext.Date.parse('03-04-2011', 'd-m-Y')` then you can use format method on Date object